# undefined reference to function in gcc pthreads C

Tags: c, function, reference, pthreads, undefined

I have a code with pthreads named `par.c`, but when I try to compile it with the command: `gcc par.c -lpthread -o par`, it gives me this :

```
/tmp/ccAzMTL8.o: In function `compare': par.c:(.text+0x414): undefined reference to `exchange'
```

the function is

```
inline void exchange(int i, int j) {
  int t;
  t = a[i];
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = t;
}

inline void compare(int i, int j, int dir) {
  if (dir==(a[i]>a[j])) 
    exchange(i,j);
}
```

And in main I have them both:

```
void compare(int i, int j, int dir);
inline void exchange(int i, int j);
```

Does anyone have any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: everything is in the same text file

Comment: i am sorry i meant a text file that i named par.c

Comment: is there any way i can sent you a pm? the code is pretty big and it won't let me post it

Comment: You could (and should) remove all unrelated parts of the source forming a Minimum Complete Verifyable Example. All logic and function bodies can be stripped. It does not need to make any sense but only show the problem.

Comment: removed obsolete comments...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming all the code you posted is in the same .c file.

I had the same problem in the past. You have to declare the implementations of the inline functions as `static inline`. `static` means the function can only be linked in the same compilation unit (like it's private to this .c file). This should be the case for inline function anyway, so I can't tell you why it makes a difference, but it worked for me.

Comment: Please always accept the answer if that solved you issue.